# Weird bug involving sliders

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm having trouble fixing a weird bug. "500+b+(500-b)/n" doesn't return what it's supposed to return. Here's an extract from my code: https://jsfiddle.net/st7bdp8z/1/

```
<html>
   <head> 
   </head>

   <body >
    <p id="txt"></p>
    <p id="txt2"></p>

    <div class="""slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="b">
    </div>

        <script>
        var n = 10;
        function route(b){
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 500+b+(500-b)/n;
            document.getElementById('txt2').innerHTML = 500-b-(500-b)/n;
        }

        document.getElementById("b").oninput = function() {
            route(this.value)
        }
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of "b" is a string. Convert it to an integer using parseInt();

So something like this:

```js
var n = 10;

function route(b) {
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 500 + b + (500 - b) / n;
  document.getElementById('txt2').innerHTML = 500 - b - (500 - b) / n;
}

document.getElementById("b").oninput = function() {
  route(parseInt(this.value))
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="b">
</div>
<p id="txt"></p>
<p id="txt2"></p>
```

Comment: Oh I thought a range input would automatically be an integer. Thank you for your help!